# transformation of uniformly distributed random variable f(x)=1/2pi into Y=cosx

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

**Let $X$ be a uniformly distributed function over $[-\pi;\pi]$.  That is
$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{2 \pi}  & -\pi\leq x\leq \pi  \\ 
0 & otherwise
\end{matrix}\right.\\
$**

**Find the probability density function of  $Y = \cos X$.**

I figured out how to derive the final result using the change of variable method, but don't quite get why it needs to be multiplied by $2$.
I cannot get the result using the other cdf method at all.

Would you please help and clarify the steps of the both methods (variable change and cdf) for this type of the problem?

$$f(x)=y=cos(x) $$

$$f^{-1} (y) = \arccos(y)$$

$$f^{-1} (y)'= 1 /  \sqrt{1-y^2}$$

$$fy(y)= \mathbf 2 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\right) \cdot \left|-1/\sqrt{1-y^2}\right| 
= \frac 1\pi \cdot \sqrt{1-y^2}$$

using cdf method

\begin{align}
Fy(y) &= P(Y \leq y) = P(\cos x \leq y) = P(x \leq -\arccos y) + P(x \geq \arccos y) \\ \\
&= \int_{-\pi}^{-\arccos(y)} \frac{1}{2 \pi} \; dx + \int_{\arccos(y)}^{\pi} \frac{1}{2 \pi} dx
  = \left[\frac{x}{2 \pi}\right]_{-\pi}^{-\arccos(y)}
    + \left[\frac{x}{2 \pi}\right]_{\arccos(y)}^{\pi} \\ \\
&= \frac{-\arccos(y)}{2 \pi} - \frac{-\pi}{2 \pi} + \frac{\pi}{2 \pi} -\frac{\arccos(y)}{2 \pi} \\ \\
&= \frac{-\arccos(y)}{2 \pi} + \frac{\pi}{2 \pi} - \frac{arccos(y)}{2 \pi} + \frac{\pi}{2 \pi} = 1- \frac{\arccos(y)}{ \pi} \\ \\
f(y) &= F'(y) = \left(1- \frac{\arccos(y)}{ \pi}\right)' = \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{1-y^2}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We deal with your question about why we multiply by $2$.  We are interested in finding the cumulative distribution function $F(y)$ of $Y$. The only interesting part is when $-1\lt y\lt 1$, because $F(y)=1$ if $y\ge 1$ and $F(y)=0$ when $y\le -1$.

It is geometrically perhaps a little easier to find $G(y)=\Pr(Y\gt y)$. Then the probability that $Y\le y$ is $1-G(y)$.  For $y$ between $-1$ and $1$, $Y\gt y)$ when $-\arccos y\lt X\lt \arccos y$.  This interval has length $2\arccos y$, and therefore for $y$ between $-1$ and $1$ we have $F(y)=1-\frac{2\arccos y}{2\pi}$.

If we deal with $F(y)$ directly, note that there are **two** intervals (of equal length) in which $\cos x\le y$.

Comment: sorry, I still can't get my head around this. I am stuck at the transformation from the P(cosx ≤ y) into the  (1−2 arccos y)/2pi

Fy(y) = P(Y≤y) = P(cosx ≤ y) = ...?... =(1−2arccosy)/2pi

Could you please clarify the stpes inbetween (which intervals for wich integral)

I was trying something like this...

Fy(y) = P(Y≤y) = P(cosx ≤ y) =

=P(x ≤ -arccos y) + P(x ≥ arccos y) = Fx(-arccos y)  + 1 - Fx(arccos y)=

1 - integral{from ??? to ???} 1/2pi dx + integral{from ??? to ???} 1/2pi dx =

1- [x / 2pi] {from ??? to ???} + [x / 2pi] {from ??? to ???} = ???

Comment: I was trying to encourage you to use $G(y)$ as an intermediate step,  since that is easier. But let us ask for example for $F(1/2)$. When is $\cos x\le 1/2$?  For $x\ge \pi/3$ and for $x\le -\pi/3$. The part with $x\ge \pi/3$ has length $\pi-\pi/3=\pi-\arccos(1/2)$. The other part has the same length, for a total of $2(\pi-\arccos((1/2))$.

Comment: I had a typo/mistake (wrong placement of parentheses) earlier, which may have given you trouble. It has been  fixed. Slightly different wording with the specific $y=1/2$ in the comment above may also help.

Comment: sorry Andre, I cannot get it  

Fy(y) = P(Y≤y) = P(cosx ≤ y) = P(x ≤ -arccos y) + P(x ≥ arccos y) = Fx(-arccos y)  + 1 - Fx(arccos y)=                                                                    is that correct to this point?                                   if yes, what integrals would be the Fx() functions converted in?

Comment: Work with $x\ge 0$, it is more familiar. For $x\lt 0$, use the fact that $\cos(-t)=\cos t$.  So for now  $x$ is positive. Since $\cos$ is **decreasing** on $[0,\pi]$, we have $\cos x\le y$ iff $x\ge \arccos(y)$. The probability that positive $x$ is $\ge \arccos y$ is $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ times the length of the interval from $\arccos y$ to $\pi$. This length is $\pi-\arccos y$. Divide by $2\pi$. We get $\frac{1-\arccos y}{2}$. Double this to deal with negative $x$. We get $F(y)=1-\frac{\arccos y}{\pi}$.

Comment: You ask for an integral. Since $X$ has uniform distribution, we are integrating the constant function $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ from $\arcos y$ to $\pi$, then doubling to deal with the part from $-\pi$ to $0$. But I don't think of it as an integral, it is just the area of a rectangle of height $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ and base from $\arccos y$ to $\pi$ (plus another rectangle with base $-\pi$ to $-\arccos y$).  The geometry, as is often the case, is critical for finding the right answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I added the solution by the cdf method to the bottom of the question. I think it ties to this what you suggested. The mistake I was doing was not referring to the initial function (uniform, the rectangle shape).  I was focusing only on the cos(x) and arccos(y) functions and I got confused. Do you think the solution I added makes sense?

Comment: You are welcome. Makes sense, gives the argument in "calculus" language where I was being  purely geometric. There is in the last line a $2\pi$ at the bottom where on the line above you have the correct $\pi$. You differentiated as if it were $\pi$, so got the right density.

Comment: 2π in the last line was a typo. Corrected. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have one further question to this problem, let's say   E(Y) was looked for
what interval needs to be taken for the  integral y*fy(y) dy  
would it be always from 0 to 1 when Y is a transformation of uniform distribution?

Comment: If you only want $E(Y)$ you can find it without finding the distribution of $Y$, by integrating $\cos x\cdot \frac{1}{2\pi}$ over the interval.  If you want to use the density function of $Y$, recall that the interval is $-1$ to $1$, not $0$ to $1$.

Comment: ok, clear thanks.

Answer (score 1):

since we have $x$ belongs to $[-\pi,\pi]$ the $\arccos(x)$ can be written with two signs ($-$ & $+$) , that's why we have:

$$fy(y)=\frac 1{ 2\pi}  |\frac{-1} {\sqrt{1-x^2}}|  +  \frac 1 {2\pi}   |\frac 1 {\sqrt{1-x^2}}|$$

So

$$fy(y)=2* \frac 1 {2\pi} *  |\frac 1 {\sqrt{1-x^2}}|$$

Finally,

$$fy(y)= \frac 1 \pi \frac 1 {\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

That's it

Best regards